# sql select group by a having count(1) > 1 equivalent in python pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a hard time filtering the `groupby` items in pandas.  I want to do

```
select email, count(1) as cnt 
from customers 
group by email 
having count(email) > 1 
order by cnt desc
```

I did

```
customers.groupby('Email')['CustomerID'].size()
```

and it gives me the list of emails and their respective counts correctly but I am not able to achieve the `having count(email) > 1` part.

```
email_cnt[email_cnt.size > 1]
```

returns `1`

```
email_cnt = customers.groupby('Email')
email_dup = email_cnt.filter(lambda x:len(x) > 2)
```

gives the whole record of customers with `email > 1` but I want the aggregate table.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of writing `email_cnt[email_cnt.size > 1]`, just write `email_cnt[email_cnt > 1]` (there's no need to call`.size` again). This uses the Boolean series `email_cnt > 1` to return only the relevant values of `email_cnt`.

For example:

```
>>> customers = pd.DataFrame({'Email':['foo','bar','foo','foo','baz','bar'],
                              'CustomerID':[1,2,1,2,1,1]})
>>> email_cnt = customers.groupby('Email')['CustomerID'].size()
>>> email_cnt[email_cnt > 1]
Email
bar      2
foo      3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 6):

Two other solutions (with modern "method chain" approach):

Using [selection by callable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
customers.groupby('Email').size().loc[lambda x: x>1].sort_values()
```

Using the [query method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental):

```
(customers.groupby('Email')['CustomerID'].
    agg([len]).query('len > 1').sort_values('len'))
```